# ARM frame pointer register (r11) keeps changing spotaneously

Tags: assembly, arm, cpu-registers

I'm debugging ARM assemblies line-by-line with hardware debugger.

What I'm seeing is very strange, frame pointer register (r11) keeps changing even the instructions are regardless of it.

For instance, while executing the following lines:

```
mov r4, r1
mov r5, r2
```

r11 registers changing from 0x00100ee8 to 0x00100eec (keep increasing by 4)

Is it some kind of hardware bug or is there some logic that I don't know?

Comment: are you sure that's not r15 (PC) ?

Comment: you are using (and trusting) a debugger for this information about r11 or you have confirmed it other ways?

Comment: The `fp` is not that critical.  A compiler may use it if it knows it is in a leaf function and certain compile options are set.  A debugger may implement stepping in various ways.  I am not sure how it is done on the ARM.  Some CPUs will change the `lr` equivalent to return to a know *debug* location.  Far too little context has been given.

Answer (score 3):

Unlikely that this is a hardware bug, since it would make the processor completely unusable.  It's more likely that the debugger is using the frame register and isn't displaying it properly. Also, I don't see a `cpy` instruction in the ARM instruction set, so I have to wonder what that translates to in the toolset you're using.

Comment: cpy is the same as mov. I will fix the question.